# Printers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printing, ip, powershell-3.0, network-printers

I just started working with PowerShell .
I would like to program an application, which  returns the IP and the Name of all Printers that are located in the Network.
The Programm should also return the paper status and the ink cartridges status. 
How do I do that?
And is this even possible?
It would be very nice if you could answer my question.
Greetings Jay.

Comment: sure, what have you done so far? are you stuck with some part of your code and need some help?

Comment: I tried with 
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer
This returns:
The Location 
Name
PrinterStatus
ShareName
And SystemName.
Of all this things, i only need the name. 
Is it possible to and a filter that only returns you the Informations that you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer | Select -Expand Name
```

To Get multiple Properties, replace the above to  `| Select Name,Status,PortName`

To Get all the available properties use:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast Answer.